# How to Unit test (junit) Android Flavor/Variant - class does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, junit4, android-productflavors

We have 2 product flavors in our app and one flavor has a class (FlavorSpecificClass) that the other does not.  We have a junit test for FlavorSpecificClass in the src/test folder which will not compile when we are on our core variant because the class does not exist in that variant.

I cannot find a way to have separate unit tests per variant and the code will not compile in our core variant unless I comment out the references to FlavorSpecificClass.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you are using gradle.

So for this you need to have another directory which rests in the same place as your 'test' directory. Name the directory as 'test[BuildVariant]'
and have the tests for that build variant inside that directory.

Suppose you have built variant debug, Your directory structure would look something like this, if you want to test classes that are just in debug build variant

```
-debug/java/...
-main/java/...
-test/java/[your tests]
-testDebug/java/[your tests for build variant debug]
```

Comment: Yes using gradle.  I tried this and it works to only run the tests under the testDebug folder when the debug variant is selected however the problem with the main variant not compiling due to the class that only exists in debug.  The class is only mentioned in the tests in the testDebug folder however the main variant will still not compile and run.

Comment: Then that means your main variant wants that class to be there. You may need to add that class in all variants. The other variants may have no-op methods.

Comment: We figured it out.  When I had created the testDebug folder I then proceeded to create the java folder by selecting New -> Folder -> Java Folder.  This automatically added 'src/testDebug/java' to my main sourceSet in build.gradle.  What worked is to just create the java folder by using New -> Directory and then the build.gradle file is never modified.

Comment: @GauravVashisth Can you tell how to combine unit test for some flavor and set it in source set for some flavor